# Python requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects: Exceeded 30 redirects

Tags: python, redirect, python-requests

I found posts with similar questions but they didn't really solve my problem.

I'm trying to find some data from Nasdaq website but got this message when sending multiple requests. My understanding is that the website is trying to redirect me to another URL which then redirect to another one and ends up in a loop but the requests library stops after a certain number of redirects. However, I'm getting an error message that's listed below. Can anyone please help with a solution?

```
import requests

header = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36'}

source1 = requests.get('http://www.nasdaq.com/earnings/report/AAPL',headers = header ).text
source2 = requests.get('http://www.nasdaq.com/earnings/report/FB',headers = header ).text
source3 = requests.get('http://www.nasdaq.com/earnings/report/AMZN',headers = header ).text
source4 = requests.get('http://www.nasdaq.com/earnings/report/BABA',headers = header ).text
source5 = requests.get('http://www.nasdaq.com/earnings/report/IBM',headers = header ).text
```

The error message is following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
source = requests.get('http://www.nasdaq.com/earnings/report/AAPL',headers = header ).text
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 72, in get
return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 58, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 508, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 640, in send
history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 640, in <listcomp>
history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 140, in resolve_redirects
raise TooManyRedirects('Exceeded %s redirects.' % self.max_redirects, response=resp)
requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects: Exceeded 30 redirects.
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to ask a question...

Comment: @Shadow Thanks I have edited my original post. My question is how can I access the website without hitting that error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try hitting `http://www.nasdaq.com/earnings/report/AAPL` in the webbrowser.
This isn't a problem with python - this site is literally redirecting you too many times.

If you read the headers on the request, you will notice that this url redirects to `http://www.nasdaq.com/earnings/report/aapl`. Then going to that url redirects you to `http://www.nasdaq.com/earnings/report/aapl` again. This is causing an infinite loop which python is correctly halting.

There's nothing you can do about this client-side. This is an error that needs to be fixed on the server. If you are in control of the server, then this might be worth another question. If not, then you'll need to get in contact with the person who is, or alternatively find another way to get the data you seek.

Comment: I know it probably didn't help you in this instance - but please consider marking this answer as accepted as it is the unfortunate truth.

Comment: How can I tell if the URL re-directs itself? Where can I find that in the headers? Sorry I'm new to programming and/or Python.

Comment: The funny thing is that I can open the URL with a browser (chrome)... but I know if I try to load the page for a couple of more times, it will show that error message, why is that?

Comment: I just noticed then that it worked. It'll be something wrong on their end. If you're on linux, you could use `wget` as a way to see where the response is taking you. Otherwise some healthy googling will get you on your way :)